# Did Stack Overflow give us a Christmas bonus?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I don't usually get a lot of points on Stack Overflow. Maybe 5 or 10 every month or two. So I was kind of surprised to see that I had a 100 new reputation points this morning. The topics appear random (PowerBuilder, SQL and Android). And 100 seems like a nice round number. So my question is, did Stack Overflow give us a bonus or is this a bug?

Comment: Hopefully the serial upvoter will read about bounties and choose to reward you that way next time.

Comment: Sometimes I just read a user's profile, and go to several of their answers and find all of them interesting, and upvote them each individually on merit.  Don't think I've ever upvoted as many as 10 though, so as not to fall foul of the auto-reverse algorithm.  Bounty doesn't really cover that situation.

Comment: I got a couple of upvotes on old answers the day my yearling badge was awarded. A nice gesture I thought.

Comment: Kinda related, asked on first Winter Bash - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159599/is-winter-bash-making-users-upvote-downvote-and-answer-randomly-to-earn-caps

Comment: yeah i to sometimes see an interesting answer or that some one got a particular badge i got and follow some answers giving votes to their q and a and of others on the same pages

Answer (score 50):

No, there wasn't a Christmas bonus.  It looks like you were serially upvoted. Maybe you recently helped someone who wanted to thank you by upvoting lots of your older posts. Unfortunately, the system is likely to reverse that serial upvoting via automated scripts.

It is apparent that this was a case of serial upvoting because of the tight clustering of the activity.  See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for more information.

[image: Picture of upvote activity]

Comment: It's worth noting that the source of the reputation can be found on the [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation) of your profile.

Comment: That's fine. I don't want votes that I didn't earn.

Comment: Judging by the time stamps, the OP shouldn't get too attached to the rep.  Most of it will probably be gone tomorrow

Comment: I thought it was odd that they all occurred at the same time.

Comment: @Slapout Enjoy it while it lasts. I believe the script runs at 3 am GST, which would be in a little more than 8 hours if I got my math right. Then you should see a nice red -100 in your rep update, annotated with something like "Serial upvoting reverted".

Comment: Note, OP, that there is nothing to worry about on your side: the script will not penalize you in any way or subject you to close scrutiny or anything, just take out the bogus rep.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: it is called "reversed", not "reverted".

Comment: @lpapp Close enough! ;) And yes, absolutely no reason to worry about it. I believe it's understood that serial upvoting is rarely malicious. I got 20 upvotes once, almost certainly by somebody who liked an answer so much that they wanted to give me more than the bounty that was already on it. It makes your rep history look kind of funny for those couple of days, but there are absolutely no negative implications otherwise.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I don't see any reversal.

Comment: @MartinSmith I hadn't checked the profile. Yes, it wasn't reversed. Kind of surprising, 10 upvotes in 4 minutes looks very unusual for a user who previously got maybe 1 vote per week. But since we can't see the underlying data, we don't know for sure if they all came from the same user.

Comment: would he get -100 rep, or -90 rep and keep the 10 that he really earned from the one answer the user originally liked?

Comment: So, its been 2 days now and it still hasnt reversed.  So it must have been from multiple people.  Very rare to get a serial upvote from multiple users.

Comment: User [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) can vote up too, maybe it actually was a "Christmas bonus"?

Comment: @paqogomez, Yes right, this is really rare. Even the script couldn't find it bogus and this isn't reversed? Good for him!

Comment: @paqogomez Rather than multiple users (which seems unlikely) it may have just been one user spacing them out well enough (had to see the exact timestamps). I was only serially upvoted once and mine wasn't reversed either; once a user went through and upvoted all my current +9 answers to +10 over the course of a half hour, resulting in a flood of Nice Answer and Enlightened badges. It wasn't detected and reversed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if you look at these they are all in the same minute.  very very odd.

Comment: @paqogomez Indeed - last time I looked, they were all still listing as "N hours ago", so I didn't see how close the timestamps actually were. Weird.